# Getting an error when I try to run an OpenSSL command to export an RSA public key from a complete PEM Certificate

Tags: openssl

I am trying to export (in RSA format) my public key using OpenSSL (this is under Git for Windows, v2.31.1). When I do this, I get the following error (all examples have been slightly modified for brevity):

```
rsa: Use -help for summary.
```

The command that I am using that throws the above error is as follows:

```
openssl rsa -in ".\PEM\INTERMEDIATE cert.pem" -RSAPublicKey_out ".\PEM\Switch\Public key.key"
```

The below command goes through without issue though, so I'm really confused as to why the one above doesn't (or at least, why is it kicking back the "rsa -in" when the other one isn't since it's literally identical in that portion):

```
openssl rsa -in ".\PEM\INTERMEDIATE cert.pem" -out ".\PEM\Switch\Private key.key"
```

I have googled and googled, but I haven't found anything relevant to my issue.

While I work to continuously learn, my OpenSSL knowledge is limited, so if I'm just missing something stupid, my apologies.

Alternatively, could someone provide me with a valid command string that would allow me to export the keypair in RSA format in one command?

Let me know if you have any questions, or need further details.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

As you are dealing with the certificate, you need to use OpenSSL's `x509` command instead:

```
openssl x509 -noout -pubkey -in ".\PEM\INTERMEDIATE cert.pem"
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmCQevRW0ut/HjKUntjgL
afO2TqgsLiEdXETfIV1+I3T+Xn60SremrR+u4AYW4ptb2Wd0a12AjymdhhvZnA2Y
bXYQKFjkZbB/Sph5n+DDMX6AK7WMwEA7EYbQy6KGNmCk1TCCbdlu0A8SBDOXX09h
WvDk+ZGr5x07vOjP9GstNHziSGEcjvNhRMxvoEqplLBN2uepNHpyOKhBzDyUEX3r
yKaMt4bLyjM72T03i/t6PoYs53PXClesZJsZ6/QPBAiKrAMXGWT0WiUijTQssvZo
HRJt04oeFNrEj6biI4XVeg29auDp7OwXu0IbZ6ol7UWDIfzByXzVYj768sUt0/3U
ZQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```